# Git is looking for a wrong SSH key

Tags: git, ssh

I decided to try using SSH to work with my GitHub repos. I modified remote url in git/.config, so now it uses SSH:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:keddad/passpoint_server.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

But when I ran *git fetch*, for example, git is looking for a wrong key:

```
(venv) keddad@keddad-pc:~/PycharmProjects/passpoint_server/.git$ git fetch
no such identity: /home/keddad/.ssh/github_rsa: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

In the same time, the real key which is added to GitHub is in a file *~/.ssh/id_rsa*
How do I make git use the *id_rsa* key?

Comment: Does `~/.ssh/config` exist? Maybe the key is configured for github in it.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes! I don't really know how it happened, but it was configured in such a way. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/correct_key
```

Answer (score 9):

Looks like my ~/.ssh/config was poorly configured:

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I needed to change the IdentityFile to a real file, in my case, *id_rsa*

```
Host github.com
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      IdentitiesOnly yes
```